# Definition of divergent series for series of real numbers and of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Divergence of a series of complex numbers is defined in the following way:

> The series
>
> $$\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n\,\,\,\,\, , a_n \in \mathbb{C}$$ **diverges** iff
>   $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} |a_n| \bigg)=+\infty$$

Does this definition hold as stated also if $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

---

Or, in that case, do we consider the limit without the absolute values? That is

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n \bigg)=\pm \infty$$

---

Or maybe would it be the same thing to consider $\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n \bigg)$ or  $\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} |a_n| \bigg)$? In particular does the following hold?

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} |a_n| \bigg)=+ \infty \iff \lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n \bigg)=\pm \infty\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: This is not the usual definition of divergence. Usually a sequence is called divergent if it is not convergent. A series is just the sequence of its partial sums, so the same applies for them.

Comment: The last equivalence is not true in general. Consider $1-1/2+1/3-1/4+\cdots$. If convergence holds also with the absolute value, we say, that the series is absolutely convergent. Absolute convergency implies convergency, but not vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The statement holds for all $a_n$ including when $a_n$ is an element of the reals.  However, this is not the way the definition is normally stated.  Generally, it is stated that a series is divergent if it is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is false.  Note that if

$$a_n=(-1)^n/n$$

The series will converge, but the absolute value of it will not.  Thus, this is called a conditionally convergent series.  If it satisfied your requirement, it would be absolutely convergent.

---

The usual definition is as follows:

A sequence is said to converge to a limit $L$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have

$$|L-s_n|<\epsilon$$

Particularly, we have

$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$

But if there does not exist an $N$ for any $\epsilon>0$, then it diverges.